# Node emitters with express

Tags: node.js, express

I want to make serial work on backend.  I want to select geo_unit and do another work and write response to client. 
I read  http://nodejs.org/docs/v0.4.7/api/events.html#events and [Error: Can't set headers after they are sent to the client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7042340/node-js-error-cant-set-headers-after-they-are-sent)

Everything works fine when I send the requests slowly e.g. 1 in each 3 seconds.

But it doesnot work when i send the requests fast. and i get the following error.
Do i define something globally?

```
Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.
    at ServerResponse.OutgoingMessage.setHeader (http.js:691:11)
    at ServerResponse.res.setHeader (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\node_modules\express\node_modules\connect\lib\patch.js:63:22)
    at ServerResponse.res.set.res.header (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:527:10)
    at ServerResponse.res.json (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\node_modules\express\lib\response.js:194:36)
    at EventEmitter. (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\routes\api_scrapper.js:17:17)
    at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    at ScrapperAPI.externalLocationCallback (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\routes\api_scrapper.js:27:20)
    at Query._callback (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\routes\api_scrapper.js:51:21)
    at Query.Sequence.end (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:78:24)
    at Query._handleFinalResultPacket (E:\git\xxxxxx-nodejs\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Query.js:143:8)
```

I am using the following code :

```
var express = require('express'),
  http = require('http'),
  path = require('path');

var app = module.exports = express();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');


var mysql = require('mysql');
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    host : 'localhost',
    user : 'root',
    database :'evevgez_development',
    password : 'root',
     // socketPath  : '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'
});

var sahibinden = require('./routes/my_scrapper').newScrapperAPI(pool);

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.bodyParser());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.errorHandler());

app.get('/node1', sahibinden.scrap);

server.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

and myModule is like that

```
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var iconv = require('iconv-lite');
var EventEmitter = require('events').EventEmitter;
var emitter= new EventEmitter();


function ScrapperAPI(pool) {
    this.scrap = function (req, res,next) {
        var query = req.query;
        console.log('req.params:'+req.query);
        console.log('IL_ID:'+query.il_id);
        emitter.emit('location',query);
        emitter.on('success',function(rows){
            res.json(rows);
        });

    };

    emitter.on('location',function(query){
        console.log('quey1:'+query);
        getExternalLocation(query )
    });

    var getExternalLocation = function (query ) {
        try {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {

                console.log('query:'+query);
                connection.query("select * from external_geo_units where geo_unit_id = ?  ",query.il_id, function (err, rows) {
                    console.log(err);
                    if (err)    callback(err);
                    emitter.emit('success',rows);
                    connection.release();
                });

            });
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(e);
        }

    };
}

module.exports.newScrapperAPI = function (pool) {
    return new ScrapperAPI(pool);
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using an EventEmitter in this way isn't the best solution for what you're doing, since you're just using it within a request to make a database call and return some rows -- something that could be more easily and simply done with just callbacks.

However if you want to keep the global EventEmitter, you have to switch the `on` in `emitter.on('success'` and `emitter.on('location'` to `once` instead, to ensure they only get called once per request.

Comment: I switched to simple callbacks. Emitters were not neccessary in that case.